# Spring batch accessing job parameter returning null value even though stepscope is used

Tags: spring

I have read this forum with lots of examples on how to use jobparameters but still got stuck as i am getting null value when retrieving jobparameter

Below is my code so far

Controller :

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/bulkimport/api/")
public class BatchController {

    @Autowired
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    public Job bulkImportJob;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/bulkProcessjob", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void batchImportProcess(@RequestHeader(value = "X-Auth-Token") String jwtToken,
                                   @RequestParam("excelfile") final MultipartFile excelfile
                                   ) throws IOException{

        String path = new ClassPathResource("importFileFolder/").getURL().getPath();
        File fileToImport = new File(path + excelfile.getOriginalFilename());

        try {

             Map<String, JobParameter> jobParametersMap = new HashMap<String, JobParameter>(); 
                jobParametersMap.put("processName", new JobParameter("processName"));
                jobParametersMap.put("operation", new JobParameter("operation"));
                jobParametersMap.put("filePath", new JobParameter(fileToImport.getAbsolutePath()));
                System.out.println(fileToImport.getAbsolutePath()+"filePath:::::::::::");
                jobLauncher.run(bulkImportJob, new JobParameters(jobParametersMap));

    }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }


}
```

Config class:

```
public String filePath;


     @Bean(name = "bulkImportJob")
    public Job bulkImportJob() {
                return jobBuilderFactory.get("bulkImportJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(bulkImportProcessStep()).end().build();
    }




    @Bean
    public Step bulkImportProcessStep() {

        return stepBuilderFactory.get("bulkImportProcessStep").<String, String> chunk(1).reader(validateFileHeader(filePath)).writer(new TempWriter()).build();

    }



    @Bean
    @StepScope
    BulkUploadExcelHeader validateFileHeader(@Value("#{jobParameters[filePath]}") String filePath) {
        System.out.println("filePath value::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"+filePath);
        return new BulkUploadExcelHeader(filePath);
    }
```

in above print statement filePath value is printed as null

can anyone please suggest what is wrong in above code

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to enclose filePath with single quotes:

`validateFileHeader(@Value("#{jobParameters['filePath']}")`